# An error Occur while creating next app by cmd

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js

```
D:\Lerning next.js>npx create-next-app ak
```

`Creating a new Next.js app in D:\Lerning next.js\ak.`

`Installing react, react-dom, and next using npm...`

`npm ERR! code ECONNRESET`
`npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET`
`npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch` https://registry.npmjs.org/next: aborted
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ashish\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-05-17T18_44_47_565Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom next has failed.`

Comment: What do you get when you run this command: `ping registry.npmjs.org`

Comment: Pinging registry.npmjs.org [2606:4700::6810:1223] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 2606:4700::6810:1223: time=109ms
Reply from 2606:4700::6810:1223: time=73ms

Ping statistics for 2606:4700::6810:1223:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 2, Lost = 2 (50% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 73ms, Maximum = 109ms, Average = 91ms

Comment: You either have a really slow network connection, or there is a network firewall. Try switching to another network and try agian.